# Making access to db static = bad?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, static

In a couple of .NET C# webservice projects that i have done i have made access to db static with help of the singleton pattern. Then the other day my friend told me that this is a bad thing to do, because if a lot of request is made for the same db entity then the db would be locked because of the static instance. Is my friends assumptations right? I thought that every new request would make a new instance of the class?

The implementation of the singleton class looks like this:

```
public class WebService
{
    private readonly IFactory _factory;

    public WebService(IFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IDataRepository Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _factory.GetDatabase();    
        }            
    }
}

public static class WebServiceImpl
{
    private static readonly WebService _webService = new WebShop(new WebserviceFactoryImpl());

    public static WebService webService { get { return _webService; } }

}
```

_factory.GetDatabase() returns a new instace of the Database class.

Comment: What's this `IFactory` interface, especially what does `GetDataBase()`  do?

Comment: It returns a new instance of Database class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `WebServiceImpl`, all calls will be sharing a single `WebService` instance. Now, this isn't *necessarily* a problem, depending on how that is implemented; for example, if `_factory.GetDatabase();` ends up getting called per-request, then it might be that you are getting away with it. Depending further on what `GetDatabase()` does - i.e. does it get a new instance per call? or does it give you the same instance every time? Simply: we don't have enough information there to answer fully. But:

- sharing a single database connection between requests is dangerous; either you need to lock / synchronize, or you risk lots of errors (database connections are not usually written to be thread-safe)
- sharing an ORM between requests is even worse: in addition to everything above, you also get issues with data accumulating in the identity / object cache; ORM instances (data-context, etc) are intended to be short-lived and then discarded (and sometimes: disposed)

Having static *access* to the database is not necessarily a problem; it all comes down to how that is implemented - for example, a static-based API could still create (and dispose) a connection on every call.

Comment: the _factory.GetDatabase() returns a new instance of the Database class, which uses the Entity framework (just for info). So i guess the implementation i posted is ok after all?

Comment: @Poku if it calls `GetDatabase()` per request, and returns a separate EF context pre `GetDatabase()`, then you should be fine, yes

Comment: they are called per requests. Thanks you clarifying this.

Comment: But be careful: Every time you access the property `Data`, a new data base connection is created. I wouldn't expect a property getter to have that big side effect. You should rather use a method `GetData()` there, I think.